# UIPickerView Empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitextfield, uipickerview

My issue is only with my picker "proPicker." The weird thing is, the objects are still in the array, as the text in my textfield changes even though the picker shows up blank....

I believe I have followed all of the steps to populate the picker, and 9 out of 10 times the picker shows the correct information, but sometimes it just shows up blank..

Here is my code:

.h:

```
    //
//  EditDebateViewController.h
//  
//
//  Created by Jacob Klapper on 10/17/13.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface EditDebateViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property UIDatePicker *pickerView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *topic;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pro;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *con;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pVotes;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cVotes;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *abs;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *date;

@property NSMutableArray *pChoices;
@property NSMutableArray *pStrings;
@property NSMutableArray *cChoices;
@property NSMutableArray *cStrings;
@property NSMutableArray *proTest;
@property UIPickerView *proPicker;

@property PFObject *obj;

@end
```

.m:

```
//
//  EditDebateViewController.m
//  
//
//  Created by Jacob Klapper on 10/17/13.
//
//

#import "EditDebateViewController.h"

@interface EditDebateViewController ()

@end

@implementation EditDebateViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    //self.date = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    self.date.delegate = self;
    self.pro.delegate = self;
    self.con.delegate = self;
    self.pVotes.delegate = self;
    self.cVotes.delegate = self;
    self.abs.delegate = self;
    self.topic.delegate = self;



    self.pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 322, 0, 0)];
    self.pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    self.pickerView.hidden = true;
    self.pickerView.date = [NSDate date];
    [self.pickerView addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(updateLabel:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //[self.view addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.pickerView];
    //self.pickerView.del
    self.date.inputView = self.pickerView;


    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy "];

    self.proPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 322, 0, 0)];
    self.proPicker.hidden = true;
    self.proPicker.delegate = self;


    [self.tableView addSubview:self.proPicker];
    self.pro.inputView = self.proPicker;

    self.pStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.cStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.pChoices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.obj objectForKey:@"PR"]];
    self.cChoices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.proTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //self.pChoices = [self.obj objectForKey:@"PR"];
    //self.cChoices = [self.obj objectForKey:@"CR"];
    NSLog(@"Choices Now: %@", self.pChoices);
    NSLog(@"Choices Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.pChoices count]);

    for (PFUser *us in self.pChoices) {
        //NSLog(@"Hi");
        //PFUser *user = [self.pChoices objectAtIndex:i];
        [us fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

            //[self.pChoices addObject:object];
            //NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
            //NSLog(name);
            //[self.proTest addObject:object];
            //NSLog(@"The value before pStrings is: %@", name);
            //[self.pStrings addObject:name];
            //NSLog(@"This is spot: %@", [self.pStrings objectAtIndex:i]);
            [self.proTest addObject:object];
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
            [self.pStrings addObject:name];
            NSLog(@"Pro Test: %@", self.proTest);
            NSLog(@"Pro Strings: %@", self.pStrings);
            NSLog(@"User: %@", us);
            NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
        }];

    }

    NSLog(@"Strings: %@", self.pStrings);
    NSLog(@"Pro Test: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.proTest count]);
    //NSLog(@"%@", self.pStrings);

    self.topic.text = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Topic"];
    self.date.text = [df stringFromDate:[self.obj objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    NSLog(@"Hi Test");
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"proVotes"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        NSLog(@"ITS NULL");
        self.pVotes.text = @"";
    }
    //self.pVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"proVotes"] ];

    else
    {

        self.pVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"proVotes"] ];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"conVotes"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
       self.cVotes.text = @"";
    }

    else
    {
        self.cVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"conVotes"] ];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"Abstentions"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        self.abs.text = @"";
    }

    else
    {
        self.abs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"Abstentions"]];
    }

  /*
    NSLog(@"Here");

    NSLog(@"%@", proU);
    self.pro.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [proU objectForKey:@"firstName"], [proU objectForKey:@"lastName"]];

    PFUser *conU = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Con"];
    //self.con.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [conU objectForKey:@"firstName"], [conU objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
    */


    PFUser *proU = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Pro"];
    [proU fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        self.pro.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
    }];

    PFUser *conU = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Con"];
    [conU fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        self.con.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
    }];

    [self.pickerView setDate:[self.obj objectForKey:@"Date"]];

    [self.proPicker reloadAllComponents];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.proPicker reloadAllComponents];
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */



- (IBAction)backcustom:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //[aTextField resignFirstResponder];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy "];

    if(textField == self.topic)
    {
        NSLog(@"Topic");
    }

    if(textField == self.date)
    {
       self.pickerView.hidden = false;
        self.date.text = [df stringFromDate:self.pickerView.date];
    }

    if(textField == self.pro)
    {
        self.proPicker.hidden = false;
        //self.pro.text =

        NSInteger rowSelectionKg = [self.proPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];                  //get currrent row of picker for first column

        NSString *tempKg = [self.pStrings objectAtIndex:rowSelectionKg];        //use row as index to get value in corresponding array of choices in picker

        self.pro.text = tempKg;
    }

    //pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    return YES;

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.proPicker) {
        self.pro.text = [self.pStrings objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    else
    {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy "];
    self.date.text = [df stringFromDate:self.pickerView.date];
    //NSString *strFirstPickerView = [_ty objectAtIndex:row];
    //_providerType.text = strFirstPickerView;
    }


}

- (void)updateLabel:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy "];
    self.date.text = [df stringFromDate:self.pickerView.date];
}

- (IBAction)saveChanges:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    [self.obj setObject:self.topic.text forKey:@"Topic"];
    [self.obj setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.pVotes.text.intValue] forKey:@"proVotes"];
    [self.obj setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.cVotes.text.intValue] forKey:@"conVotes"];
    [self.obj setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.abs.text.intValue] forKey:@"Abstentions"];

    [self.obj setObject:self.pickerView.date forKey:@"Date"];
    NSLog(@"Saving...");
    [self.obj saveInBackground];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"afterSave" sender:self];
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Section: %ld", (long)[indexPath section]);
    NSLog(@"Row: %ld", (long)[indexPath row]);

    if([indexPath section] == 1 && [indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Right Cell");
        UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Debate" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        popupQuery.tag = 1;

        [popupQuery showInView:self.view];


    }


}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(actionSheet.tag == 1)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self.obj deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"afterSave" sender:self];
                //[self loadObjects];
            }];
        }
    }


}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    if(pickerView == self.proPicker)
    {
        NSLog(@"First Log");
        NSLog(@"In numComponents: %@",self.pStrings);
       return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView == self.proPicker)
    {
        NSLog(@"Right Picker");
        NSLog(@"Count in numRows: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.pStrings count]);
        return [self.pStrings count];
    }
    //return [_ty count];
    return [self.pStrings count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if(pickerView == self.proPicker)
    {
        NSLog(@"Picked goooood");
        return [self.pStrings objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return [self.pStrings objectAtIndex:row];

}

@end
```

Comment: I don't understand this `[self.tableView addSubview:self.pickerView];`

Comment: This is my other picker, that line adds it to the view...my issues are with my picker "proPicker"

Answer (score 1):

The `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` call is asynchronous.

This line:

```
 [self.pStrings addObject:name];
```

fills in the data into self.pStrings.

You are expecting its values to be filled in by the time you hit this call:

```
   [self.proPicker reloadAllComponents];
```

at the end of your viewDidLoad method.  You somehow need to not reloadAllComponents until that data is loaded.

I would recommend adding a BOOL to track if you've already reloaded the components.  If you have, just do it again at the end of fetching the data.  Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    __block BOOL hasCompletedSetup = NO;
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    //self.date = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    self.date.delegate = self;
    self.pro.delegate = self;
    self.con.delegate = self;
    self.pVotes.delegate = self;
    self.cVotes.delegate = self;
    self.abs.delegate = self;
    self.topic.delegate = self;



    self.pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 322, 0, 0)];
    self.pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    self.pickerView.hidden = true;
    self.pickerView.date = [NSDate date];
    [self.pickerView addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(updateLabel:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //[self.view addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.pickerView];
    //self.pickerView.del
    self.date.inputView = self.pickerView;


    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy "];

    self.proPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 322, 0, 0)];
    self.proPicker.hidden = true;
    self.proPicker.delegate = self;


    [self.tableView addSubview:self.proPicker];
    self.pro.inputView = self.proPicker;

    self.pStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.cStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.pChoices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.obj objectForKey:@"PR"]];
    self.cChoices = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.proTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //self.pChoices = [self.obj objectForKey:@"PR"];
    //self.cChoices = [self.obj objectForKey:@"CR"];
    NSLog(@"Choices Now: %@", self.pChoices);
    NSLog(@"Choices Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.pChoices count]);

    for (PFUser *us in self.pChoices) {
        //NSLog(@"Hi");
        //PFUser *user = [self.pChoices objectAtIndex:i];
        [us fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

            //[self.pChoices addObject:object];
            //NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
            //NSLog(name);
            //[self.proTest addObject:object];
            //NSLog(@"The value before pStrings is: %@", name);
            //[self.pStrings addObject:name];
            //NSLog(@"This is spot: %@", [self.pStrings objectAtIndex:i]);
            [self.proTest addObject:object];
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
            [self.pStrings addObject:name];
            NSLog(@"Pro Test: %@", self.proTest);
            NSLog(@"Pro Strings: %@", self.pStrings);
            NSLog(@"User: %@", us);
            NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
        }];
        if (hasCompletedSetup) {
            [self.proPicker reloadAllComponents];
        }        
    }

    NSLog(@"Strings: %@", self.pStrings);
    NSLog(@"Pro Test: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.proTest count]);
    //NSLog(@"%@", self.pStrings);

    self.topic.text = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Topic"];
    self.date.text = [df stringFromDate:[self.obj objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    NSLog(@"Hi Test");
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"proVotes"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        NSLog(@"ITS NULL");
        self.pVotes.text = @"";
    }
    //self.pVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"proVotes"] ];

    else
    {

        self.pVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"proVotes"] ];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"conVotes"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        self.cVotes.text = @"";
    }

    else
    {
        self.cVotes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"conVotes"] ];
    }
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"Abstentions"] ] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        self.abs.text = @"";
    }

    else
    {
        self.abs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.obj objectForKey:@"Abstentions"]];
    }

    /*
     NSLog(@"Here");

     NSLog(@"%@", proU);
     self.pro.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [proU objectForKey:@"firstName"], [proU objectForKey:@"lastName"]];

     PFUser *conU = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Con"];
     //self.con.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [conU objectForKey:@"firstName"], [conU objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
     */


    PFUser *proU = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Pro"];
    [proU fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        self.pro.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
    }];

    PFUser *conU = [self.obj objectForKey:@"Con"];
    [conU fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        self.con.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object objectForKey:@"firstName"], [object objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
    }];

    [self.pickerView setDate:[self.obj objectForKey:@"Date"]];

    hasCompletedSetup = YES;
    [self.proPicker reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Comment: But how does this cause the picker to show empty only 1 in 10 times? Is it just random, then?

Comment: It is usually done in time, but some times it is not.  That is a symptom of an asynchronous task running in background, and doing things whenever it feels like it.  If your phone is busy doing something else, it blows off your request for data until it feels like doing it.  Kind of like a teenager, or an Android device.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but my picker still showed up empty..on the first try! :( Any other ideas? This is really weird...

Comment: No ideas.  Wow! that is wierd.

Comment: Anyone else have some ideas? This is really weird and I need to fix it to get my app out there....

Comment: Hello Jacob, i have the same weird problem with my PickerView. At any point of time this empty pickerView shows up although i can see that the right data gets fetched in the background. Have you found a solution for the problem yet?